# How do I get a tensor representing the "on" positions in the original tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a Tensorflow label that may be exemplified by any of the following: [1, 2], [3], []. The first has two classes, the second has one class, and the third has none. I'd like to then turn that these another tensor that looks like the following:

```
[1, 2] --> [0, 1, 1, 0].
[3] --> [0, 0, 0, 1].
[] --> [0].
```

The number of classes is defined beforehand (here it's 3). In some sense, this is the inverse of this question - [Tensorflow Extract Indices Not Equal to Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46144429/tensorflow-extract-indices-not-equal-to-zero).

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
sparse_categories = tf.convert_to_tensor([[1 if k == i else 0 for k in range(num_categories+1)] for i in range(num_categories+1)])
values = tf.cond(tf.size(values) > 0, lambda: values, lambda: [0])
values = tf.reduce_sum(tf.gather(sparse_categories, values))
```